# Does re-heating something "reset" the spoil timer?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, spoilage

I cooked a lot of pasta sauce a few days back, and have much of it in my fridge. I intent to use it all shortly, and would prefer to not freeze it.

If I heat it back up in a pot, and let is cook all the way through, does this "reset" the time before it spoils?

I fully understand the consistency will change, and I'm OK with that - I do like a thicker sauce.

Soliciting answers specific to this question.

Comment: I'm almost positive there's a question and answer on this stack that covers this, but can't find it. Lacking the actual knowledge about how things work on a bacterial size, I'll just say and repeat what my parents, my parents parents, and, presumably, _their_ parents said: **Do not reheat twice**. Cook, freeze/cool, cook. Not cook, freeze/cool, cook, freeze/cool, cook.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Twice Baked Potatoes? lol

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/16872/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20978/67 .  But it might be worth mentioning -- tomato sauce is acidic, so there's a little less risk.  But for some things, if you cool it off / heat it up too slowly and don't bring it back up to pathogen killing temp, it might *never* be safe.  (because the bacteria reproduce and go to spore or create toxins that can't be killed at high heat)

Comment: And nothing wrong w/ frozen sauce.  It comes in handy on those days you're in a rush or bring lazy.

Comment: I don't think it is a dup of that question.

Comment: "I fully understand the consistency will change, and I'm OK with that - I do like a thicker sauce." - - It will not, if you add a little water)

Comment: @Joe: Nothing wrong with frozen sauce indeed. Freezing it by portion is my method of operation. When needed, unfreeze required amounts, prepare, eat, and no need to reheat twice.

Comment: @paparazzo: I tend to agree, but that might be because I don't know enough about the subject. The "duplicate" seems to be talking about keeping stuff warm all the time, and periodically reheating it to a high enough temperature. This one seems to cool everything down (freeze?), then reheat it, re-cool it completely, and then reheat it. Whether that matters or not, I don't know. Might be the same from a food safety point of view.